# Single page application with login and search robots

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, singlepage

In my work with a Javascript single page application, i have recently run into a problem.
The whole idea behind this project, is to avoid page reload. When the user comes to my application they won't need to make any reloads. This is done with jQuery and Backbone.js and PHP as service.

I have this static index.html file, where i hide my login container and application container. Then i show the login container, if the user is not recognize by my application, and if they have auth i show the application.

```
if auth:
  application.show()
elif not auth:
  login.show() // like Gmail or Facebook etc.: Information + login-form
```

I wan't to show users who aren't authenticated, both login-form and general info. Very important is also that the site can be found by robots as Google etc.

Can this only be done with 2 different files, giving me reload? A site.com and login.site.com. That solution irritates me, because my login, as it is by now, is quite instant.

Comment: Are you using Backbone.Controller? Why can't you route `#login` to your login page? I am doing a single-page application with the login page rendered on the client side. After the user logs in, I change `window.location.hash` to route to a different page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get the question completely but if you want to check if a user in authenticated, try to do an ajax call. If it fails with "401 unauthorized" the user needs to login...

Comment: @Julien that is not my problem. All that is actually working well now. My problem is, that i need this landingpage, where both login-form and information can be. Just like Gmail does it, with general info plus the login-box..

Comment: My question is: Is it possible to make javascript single page application where i have authentication. And at the sametime get Google Searchbot to seek my public site, that is, the site where people not yet is signed in. Gmail does this, but they have redirect after you get authenticated. My question is, to make authentication without reload and still maintain this landingpage where Google can crawl. Don't know if that was more precise?

Comment: Ah. For the bots, you need to have your public page directly in the HTML (the preferred way to handle backbone view anyways). Then you controller upon auth will replace the DOM with user specific HTML.

Comment: Thanks Julien, but won't that give some blink between loginform and user specific html, when the user refreshes (manual) and is logged in? Then the html is loaded (loginform) and then i remove it and replace it with user specific html - that most give a blink?

Comment: Yup most likely. That is why google, apple and most people doing single page app have the login before loading the actual app. There is a page refresh but it is clean cut between app and web page.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by using ajax calls to authenticate (Although this is not a recommended approach, and people usually prefer the two page solution you have outlined).

What you can do, is have very skinny controllers that just exist to provide data to rich client UI. 
Your gateway controller(A separate controller, with no model that acts as an entry point in the application) will just render the basic application structure to the client (without any user specific data, you dont know if the user is logged in, you dont need to know at this point). Then the client will query the UserController for identity of currently logged in user, if user is logged in server returns a json response containing information related to user and if not, server returns a response saying that user is not logged in. Then you can fetch a partial for the login form and then submit it again through ajax. As you see, creating the UI once and communicating with the server with lightweight ajax calls can solve your issue easily.